# Egyptian fraction of length 3 in the interval (0.5,1)

Tags: number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

I've been exploring the properties of [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction), which are representations of numbers as sums of distinct unit fractions.

Specifically, I'm interested in numbers $a$ such that $
0.5 < a < 1$ and $ a $ can be expressed as an Egyptian fraction of length 3.

Is it always the case that such a number $ a $ will have an Egyptian fraction representation of length 3 that contains $
\frac{1}{2}$? In other words, is there any number in the interval $
(0.5, 1)$ that can be represented as an Egyptian fraction of length 3, but cannot be so represented with an Egyptian fraction of length 3 containing $\frac{1}{2}$?

For example $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}$ can also be represented with $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{30}$

I don't seem to be able to find any counterexamples!

Any insights or proofs related to this would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I proved computationally that there is not such a number.

Comment: I don't know. Try $1/3+1/7+1/11$.

Comment: This is equal to 1/2 + 1/15 + 1/2310

Comment: Note that If $1/2<1/3+1/a+1/b<1$ with $3<a<b$, then $a\le11$. For each $a$ with $7\le a\le11$, there are only finitely many values of $b$ that yield $1/3+1/a+1/b>1/2$. It shouldn't be hard to analyze that finite set of cases with $a\ge7$, which leaves the harder cases with $4\le a\le6$.

Comment: I checked all of the possibilities and there is no such a number. I updated my question to a new one here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796456/egyptian-fraction-of-a-number-in-the-interval-0-5-1

Comment: Ah, I should have seen: $1/3+1/4=1/2+1/12$, $1/3+1/5=1/2+1/30$, $1/3+1/6=1/2$.

Comment: We have so many other possibilities, For example 1/4 + 1/7 + 1/9. But all of them can be written with 1/2 too, here 1/2 + 1/1235 + 1/63756

Comment: I meant for the original question, with one-third.

Comment: @Peyman Smaller denominators: $1/4 + 1/7 + 1/9 = 1/2+1/468+1/546$.