# Egyptian fraction of a number in the interval (0.5,1)

Tags: number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

Assume the real number $a$ such that $0.5 < a < 1$ and $a$ can be expressed as an [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) of length $l$, wich means for natural numbers $n_1$ to $n_l$ we have:

$$
a = \sum^l_1{\frac{1}{n_i}}
$$
for example $a = \frac{47}{60}$ can be written as $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}$ or $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{30}$

> Prove that for any $a$ in the interval $(0.5, 1)$, if an Egyptian
> fraction of length $l$ exists, there should also exist an
> Egyptian fraction of length $l$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$ in it.
> (Or come up with a counter-example)

P.S. My question comes from my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796233/egyptian-fraction-of-length-3-in-the-interval-0-5-1). Although I can't provide a straightforward mathematical proof, my computer evaluation (checking all possibilities) shows there is no such a number.

Comment: Do you mean "Although I can't..." ?

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Thanks for noticing.